# Different ways to retrieve a string form R.java file (Android)

Tags: java, android, string

Let's imagine we had this text inside *values/strings.xml*

```
<string name="some_text">HELLO WORLD</string>
```

I can call this string from anywhere inside my project like so:

```
String s = String.valueOf(R.string.some_text);
```

Today I learnt this other way to do exactly the same job:

```
String s = getResources().getString(R.string.some_text);
```

Does anyone know if there is any advantage in using the second way? The first one seems shorter and easier to remember.

Thanks

Comment: That is the first that I have seen of `String.valueOf( )` working.  Intriguing if true as then I wouldn't need to call `getResources( ) `from odd locations that might not have immediate access to them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure String.valueOf(R.string.some_text) will turn whatever the int identifier value is for that string into a String representation of that number.  Not what you want.  Also, if you are calling getString from an Activity or a Fragment, you don't have to call getResources() first as there is a convenience getString method you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compare or output the value of `s` for the two methods. They are not the same :) `String.valueOf(R.string.some_text)` returns string representation of a resource id integer. `getResources().getString(R.string.some_text);` probably does what you wanted.

Correct way is `getResources().getString(R.string.some_text);` and there are other convenience methods as mentioned by @danny117 but they are dependant of the location of the  specific code

Answer (score 1):

Look at the class your working with.  For example the fragment class has a built in getString() function so you can just call it.

[`getString(R.string.me`)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getString%28int%29)